# Exim4 working fine at sending emails, except to addresses with the fully-qualified domain in them

Tags: ubuntu, exim, smarthost

Exim is always touch-and-go for me to configure, since I only touch it once every 4 or 5 years when I have to make email work on a new server.  As a result, I'm now having a problem where all the emails being sent out by the server, (which is using a smarthost with rackspace), are working fine and being sent out...

...except some emails being sent to addresses with the local fully-qualified-domain-name.

The server is able to send out mail successfully to:

```
myemail@gmail.com
randomusers@gmail.com
```

Can't send or route to:

```
customerservice@bitlucid.com
james@bitlucid.com
```

Strangely, it can send out to:

```
root@bitlucid.com
```

Perhaps because it's set up in /etc/aliases to go to my gmail address instead.

Here is the related exim config: `cat update-exim4.conf.conf`

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='satellite'
dc_other_hostnames='www.bitlucid.com;bitlucid.com;saturnalias'
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1;::1;100.100.10.77;10.100.90.10'
dc_readhost='bitlucid.com'
dc_relay_domains=''
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost='secure.emailsrvr.com::25'
hosts_require_tls='secure.emailsrvr.com'
tls_tempfail_tryclear='false'
#tls_verify_certificates = /etc/ssl/certs
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='false'
dc_hide_mailname='true'
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='mail_spool'
```

Here is a test of the customerservice@bitlucid.com address:

```
exim -bt customerservice@bitlucid.com
R: system_aliases for customerservice@bitlucid.com
customerservice@bitlucid.com is undeliverable: Unrouteable address
```

So how do I get email to send out to `customerservice@bitlucid.com` when `bitlucid.com` is the current FQDN, but I'm pushing mail out to a smarthost (secure.emailsrvr.com)?

Comment: Old question, but no answer. But it's exactly the problem I am trying to solve now. Did you succeed solving yours?

Answer (score 2):

Your exim4 install is set up as a satellite, which means it won't do any local delivery. It's also set up as the destination for bitlucid.com emails (other than the one you redefined in aliases). So, it sees "@bitlucid.com goes to me" as well as "I don't receive local mail", and declares the mail unroutable.

Change 'satellite' to 'smarthost', and it will do what I think you're trying to do.